# uploading only a particular type of file using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload

The below HTML element is allowing all types of files to upload.

```
<input type="file" name="fileUploaded"/>
```

I want to restrict the file type to `.txt` only, how do I achieve this?

I am using Apache Commons FileUpload API and Spring framework.

Comment: tried any Flash based uploader, or Java Applet based uploader? you can have size wize restrictions and many more stuffs.

Comment: You can also try Apache FileUpload for this purpose.Visit http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

It is a JavaScript based solution that generates a Flash based uploader.

Here is what they have done in the second demo (custom demo):

```
$(function() {
    $('#custom_file_upload').uploadify({
      'uploader'       : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
      'script'         : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
      'cancelImg'      : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
      'folder'         : '/uploads',
      'multi'          : true,
      'auto'           : true,
      'fileExt'        : '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
      'fileDesc'       : 'Image Files (.JPG, .GIF, .PNG)',
      'queueID'        : 'custom-queue',
      'queueSizeLimit' : 3,
      'simUploadLimit' : 3,
      'removeCompleted': false,
      'onSelectOnce'   : function(event,data) {
          $('#status-message').text(data.filesSelected + ' files have been added to the queue.');
        },
      'onAllComplete'  : function(event,data) {
          $('#status-message').text(data.filesUploaded + ' files uploaded, ' + data.errors + ' errors.');
        }
    });
```